# Recursive databse query to build a ul list

Tags: php, parent-child

I have a database table I have to build a UL list from

the table is setup like 
cat-id 
parent-id (is the cat-id of whatever the parent is)
cat-name
cat-image

I can get the root cat easily which has a parent-id of "0" 
but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it so the end result is

rootcat
--childParent
---child

```
function cats(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cats";
        $cats;
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->vars["host"], $this->vars["user"], $this->vars["pass"], $this->vars["db"]);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            print "START MYSQLI ERROR<br/>".
            mysqli_connect_error() .
            "<br/>ENDMYSQLI ERROR";
        }else{
            $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
                while($cat = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    if($cat["parent-id"] == "0"){
                        $cats[] = $cat["cat-name"];
                    }
                }
            }
            mysqli_free_result($res);
            mysqli_close($con);
            return $cats;
        }
```

Comment: What output array are you trying to implement? show your category table structure also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse a sub category like this, but it does requirer to make a sql connection every time you check what categories does parent has:

```
function cats(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cats";
    $cats;
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->vars["host"], $this->vars["user"], $this->vars["pass"], $this->vars["db"]);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        print "START MYSQLI ERROR<br/>".
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        "<br/>ENDMYSQLI ERROR";
    }else{
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
            while($cat = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                if($cat["parent-id"] == "0"){
                    $cats[$key] = $cat["cat-name"];
                    $sql_subCategory = "SELECT * FROM cats where parent_id=". $cat["id"];
                            $res_sub = mysqli_query($con, $sql_subCategory);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($res_sub) > 0){
                                while($cat_sub = $res_sub->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                   $cats[$cat["cat-name"]] = $cat_sub["cat-name"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                mysqli_free_result($res_sub);
                mysqli_free_result($res);
                mysqli_close($con);
                return $cats;
            }
```

That should give you the array:

```
array(
    'cat1' => 'Some Category',
    'cat2' => array(
        'sub1' => 'name',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended with is totally recursive

```
    public function cats($id){      
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->vars["host"], $this->vars["user"], $this->vars["pass"], $this->vars["db"]);
    $cats;
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        print "START MYSQLI ERROR<br/>".
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        "<br/>ENDMYSQLI ERROR";
    }else{
        $cats[] = $this->child($id, $con);
        mysqli_close($con);
        return $cats;
    }
}
function child($id,$con){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `parent-id`= '".$id."'";
//  print $sql ."<br/>";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
            while($cat = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                    $cats[]["cat-name"] = $cat["cat-name"];
                    $sql_subCat = "SELECT * FROM `cats` WHERE `parent-id` = '".$cat["cat-id"]."'";
                    $res_sub = mysqli_query($con, $sql_subCat);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($res_sub) > 0){
                        while($cat_sub = $res_sub->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                            $cats[$cat["cat-name"]][] = $cat_sub["cat-name"] ;
                            $cats[$cat["cat-name"]]= $this->child($cat["cat-id"],$con);
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
        mysqli_free_result($res_sub);
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        return $cats;
}
```